# How can I crop a layer in GIMP without shrinking the canvas?

Tags: gimp, image-editing, crop, canvas

A very simple exercise in GIMP: create a new (blank) image, open a .jpg image as a new layer, and crop that layer.

**What should happen:** the canvas should stay the same size, regardless of how much or little the layer is cropped.

**What does happen:** after cropping, the canvas shrinks to the size of the area selected as the cropped image.

**Example:** First I create a new image. It's rather large at 7200 pixels wide.

[image: create image]

Then I bring a JPG into GIMP by selecting **File > Open As Layers**. The image is much smaller than my GIMP canvas, so I size it up a bit. I activate the crop tool and select part of the layer:

[image: ready to crop]

When I hit enter, the canvas outside the newly-cropped area has been filled with black (note my background and foreground colors are both white). The canvas has in fact shrunk to the selected area. (Image > Canvas Size and the title bar confirm this.)

[image: cropped]

I confirmed that **Image > Canvas Size** can be used to expand the canvas beyond the cropped area, which can get me to the result I originally expected. However, this takes an extra, tedious step of resizing the canvas. Can anyone explain if I'm doing something wrong? I'm hoping there is a mundane explanation.

I'm using GIMP v. 2.10.8 on Debian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a mundane explanation, if by default the crop tool deals with the image, it also has a `Current layer only` option:

[image]

You can also make a selection (any shape) and use `Layer > Crop to selection`. This will crop the layer to the bounding box of the selection (which is the same as the selection for a rectangle selection).